# Passing 2D array to a function

Tags: c++, arrays

I have three files:
array.cpp
array.h
array1.cpp

array.cpp sends a 2 dimentional array to the function defined in array1.cpp.

Problem is when I print the results then I get all zeros and in the end segmentation fault. Please help me where I am doing wrong?

**array1.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>
#include "array1.h"


using namespace std;

void test3(int **b, int rows, int cols);


void test3(int **b, int rows, int cols){

for (int i=0 ;i< rows; i++)
{
  for(int j=0;j<cols;j++){

  cout << b[i][j] << endl;
}
}}
```

**array.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "array1.h"

 using namespace std;

 void test3(int **b, int rows, int cols);


int main() {

 int **a;
 a = new int*[3];

for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
 {
   a[i] = new int[2]; } 

    for(int StateNum=0; StateNum<3; StateNum++  ) 
                                      {

                                           a[StateNum][0]=4;
                                           a[StateNum][1]=3;
                                      }
    int rows=3;
    int cols;2;
    cout << "popppp" << endl;  
    test3(a,rows,cols);

    for (int i=0;i< rows;i++)
     {
      free (a[i]);
      }
       free(a);
     return 0;
   }
```

**array1.h**

```
#ifndef ARRAY1_H_
#define ARRAY1_H_
 #include <string>

 using namespace std;

 void test3(int **b, int rows, int cols);

 #endif
```

Comment: I think you meant "int cols=2;" not "int cols;2;" - with the current code, cols is uninitialized.

Comment: I think `test3` causes undefined behavior.

Comment: @CharlieTangora thank u for pointing it out. DOn't know why I didn't noticed it first..

Comment: This code doesn't compile. Is a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org) too much to ask?

Comment: Also, you should not use `free` use `delete[]` in this case

Comment: @Beta during compilation, I didn't get any errors ...

Comment: @UchiaItachi: Good observation...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake-- I miscopied.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the problem:
int cols;2;
I think it should be int cols = 2;

Comment: @Rikayan, Charlie and I posted at the same time.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay: He wrote it as a comment, though. If you snooze you lose.